# How do I print Java to a window

Tags: java, printing, console, window

I have a bit of code I'm writing just for fun and to help me get familiar with process.
I am very new to Java programming so please bear with me.

Currently, I am just writing in Notepad++ and compiling in the command prompt, but I would like to learn how to compile and print my output to a window rather than have it print into the command prompt.

```
public class SalesCalculations {
    public static void main (String args[]){
    //This section is shirt sales calculations

    int shirtCost;
    shirtCost = 12;

    int shirtSales;
    shirtSales = 200;

    int shirtSalePrice;
    shirtSalePrice = 25;

    int shirtMakeCost;
    shirtMakeCost = shirtCost * shirtSales;

    int shirtSaleTotal;
    shirtSaleTotal = shirtSalePrice * shirtSales;

    int shirtProfit;
    shirtProfit = shirtSaleTotal - shirtMakeCost;

    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Cost to make Shirt:             " + "$" +  shirtCost);
    System.out.println("Sales Price of Shirt:           " + "$" +  shirtSalePrice);
    System.out.println("Number of Shirt sales:          " +  shirtSales);
    System.out.println("This months Shirt making price: " + "$" +  shirtMakeCost);
    System.out.println("Shirt sales money this month:   " + "$" +  shirtSaleTotal);
    System.out.println("Profit of Shirts:               " + "$" +  shirtProfit);
    System.out.println("");

    }
}
```

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you could use the JOptionPane class  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html  for example `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Cost to make Shirt:             " + "$" +  shirtCost);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to compile if it is not yet clear, create your file with .java go to command prompt and run

```
javac filename.java
```

you create a new file with `.class` extension that will execute without the extension with the command

```
java filename
```

you could use the [JOptionPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.ht%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bml%20for%20example) class to print the results in a dialog considering that `"\n"` will cause a line break, for example in its code would be

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Cost to make Shirt:           " + "$" +  shirtCost + "\n "
    + "Sales Price of Shirt:           " + "$" +  shirtSalePrice + " \n " 
    + "Number of Shirt sales:          " +  shirtSales + "\n" 
    + "This months Shirt making price: " + "$" +  shirtMakeCost + "\n"
    + "Shirt sales money this month:   " + "$" +  shirtSaleTotal + "\n" 
    + "Profit of Shirts:               " + "$" +  shirtProfit);
```

to work must import the class

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
```

For data graphically class it provides the `input` method for example

```
int x = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Input Value "));
```

> remember that this method returns a string so it is necessary to
>   convert it to an integer

Comment: Does this option require me to import any libraries?

Comment: yes, you must import the class JOptionPane update my answer

Comment: This is just what I was looking for. Much appreciated.

Comment: Would I be able to add an input box with this method?
Somewhere for the user to edit the number of shirts sold (shirtSales). 
And a submit button to recompile the code with the new value?

Comment: Yes, upgrade my answer

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. You have been more than helpful. Thank You

Comment: is good to help, do not forget to accept my answer, thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you are a beginner to Java you could always use the command prompt to compiling and executing java code.

1. Go to command prompt
2. compile your .java file using the java compiler *javac* like

   javac java_filename.java

   your intermediale code is generated into a .class file.
3. Execute your java code

   java java_filename

Comment: Thanks CodeRex, But in my question I state that I am currently already compiling and executing all of my code within command prompt and that while I will still be doing that, I wanted another way to display that info. Like within a modal window. Dev. Joel had an excellent solution.